# Pandas - Get dummies for only certain values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `Pandas` series of 10000 rows which is populated with a single alphabet, starting from A to Z. 
However, I want to create dummy data frames for only A, B, and C, using Pandas `get_dummies`.
How do I go around doing that?

I don't want to get dummies for all the row values in the column and then select the specific columns, as the column contains other redundant data which eventually causes a Memory Error.

Comment: So are you wanting to filter the df first or you want to `get_dummies` only for those values?

Comment: I want to get_dummies only for those values.

Comment: Note: you can solve a lot of memory problems with `get_dummies`'s `sparse=True` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
# create mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( {'alpha':['a','a','b','b','c','e','f','g']})

# use replace with a regex to set characters d-z to None
pd.get_dummies(df.replace({'[^a-c]':None},regex =True))
```

output:

```
  alpha_a   alpha_b     alpha_c
0   1   0   0
1   1   0   0
2   0   1   0
3   0   1   0
4   0   0   1
5   0   0   0
6   0   0   0
7   0   0   0
```

Comment: What if my categorical variables were random strings, lets say, names such as John, Jane and Mary, instead of a, b, and c?

Comment: you could use a list of the names you wish to exclude. `pd.get_dummies(df.replace(['Tom','Ben'],[None,None]))`