# Wanting to get_dummies for the most frequest values in a column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I am working on a program to go through tweets and predict whether the author falls into one of two categories. I want to get_dummies for whether or not a tweet contains any of the top 10 hashtags or if it contains 'other'. *(In the end I will probably be using the top 500 or so hashtags not just 10, the data set is over 500,000 columns in total with over 50,000 unique hashtags)*

This is my first time using pandas, so apologies if my question is unclear, but I think what I'm expecting is each row in the data set would be given a new column, one for each hashtag, and then the value of that [row][column] pair would be 1 if the row contains that hashtag or 0 if it does not. There would also be a column for other indicating it has other hashtags not in the top 10.

I know how to determine the most frequently occurring in the column already

```
counts = df.hashtags.value_counts()
counts.nlargest(10)
```

I also understand how to get dummies, I just don't know how to add the parameter of not making one for every hashtag.

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['hashtags'])
```

Please let me know if I could be clearer or provide more info. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Get dummies for only certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503724/pandas-get-dummies-for-only-certain-values)

Comment: I don't believe so, I'm not going through a specifically ordered dataset, so I can't set it to consider between a-c and not d-z like they are. The hashtags are unique and not in any specific order. The question would be instead of a-c, how can I make it the top most frequent occurring things in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have time to gen data and work it all out.  But though I'd get you this idea in case it might help you out.

The idea is to leverage `.isin()` to get the values that you need to build the dummies.  Then leverage the power of the index to match to the source rows.

Something like:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['hashtags'].isin(counts.nlargest(10).index)], columns=['hashtags'])
```

You will have to see if the indices will give you what you need.

Comment: So this works almost perfectly for what I need. Currently the way it works its only returning the rows that have at least one of the hashtags, is there anyway I can add another column that's basically for all the other hashtags not in the top so it till keeps all the rows in the data set?

Comment: Try something like `pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1).fillna(0)`.  It leaves a little mess around that has to be cleaned up - like the dummy dtypes and dup column(s).  But again, sorry, not enough time to really give you a full answer.  Just wanted to get you some quick info to maybe get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely puts me in the right direction. For some reason the number of rows is a little less than the original dataset. But the columns are perfect after I clean up the duplicates. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Actually all the rows are there, so its all good! Thanks again!!